# How can I solve $\dot{y} = 2t(y + y^2)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve $$\dot{y} = 2t(y + y^2)$$
I've seen something like this can be done with a transformation, say:
$$ t^\alpha$$

But I can't understand the logic behind the transformation. I would love your perspective.

Comment: Hint: this is a separable differential equation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\frac {dy} {y+y^{2}}=2tdt$. So $\int \frac 1 {y+y^{2}}dy=t^{2}+C$. This can be written as $\int [\frac 1 y -\frac 1 {1+y}]dy=t^{2}+C$ or $\log \frac y {1+y}=t^{2}+C$. Hence $y=\frac {e^{t^{2}+C}}{1-e^{t^{2}+C}}$.

Comment: You forgot the exponantial, the solution is $y(t) = \frac{e^{t^2+C}}{1-e^{t^2+C}}$

Comment: @E.Bellec Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming $y\neq 0,-1$.  It is a separable equation
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{y+y^2}=2t\,\mathrm{d}t.
$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: You have

$$ \frac{1}{y(y+1)}\,y' = 2t$$